# Angular-CLI installation issue

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I'm trying to "angular-cli", 
I type following on my command prompt (Administrator) 
"npm install -g angular-cli@latest" i get following

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g angular-cli@latest npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git npm WARN addRemoteGit     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roam ing\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:14:12) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo dules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:69:19) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo dules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:81:29) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul es\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:90:16 npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul es\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:44:5 npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul es\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:29:5 npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul es\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29 npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15) npm WARN addRemoteGit  webpack/compression-webpack-plugin#7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25 a660acc6a2a6453f54 resetting remote C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cac he\_git-remotes\git-github-com-webpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd5 4a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54-ec76b2fe because of error: { [Error: not found: g it] code: 'ENOGIT' } npm ERR! git clone
--template=C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_gi t-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/webpack/compression-webpack-plugi n.git C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com
-webpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54
-ec76b2fe: undefined npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_gi t-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/webpack/compression-webpack-plugi n.git C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com
-webpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54
-ec76b2fe: undefined npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git npm WARN addRemoteGit     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roam ing\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:14:12) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo dules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:69:19) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo dules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:81:29) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul es\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:90:16 npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul es\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:44:5 npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul es\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:29:5 npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul es\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29 npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15) npm WARN addRemoteGit  webpack/compression-webpack-plugin#7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25 a660acc6a2a6453f54 resetting remote C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cac he\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-webpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55 907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54-541c96f3 because of error: { [Error: not fo und: git] code: 'ENOGIT' } npm ERR! git clone
--template=C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_gi t-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/webpack/compression-webpack-plu gin.git C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-gi thub-com-webpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2 a6453f54-541c96f3: undefined npm ERR! git clone
--template=C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_gi t-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/webpack/compression-webpack-plu gin.git C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-gi thub-com-webpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2 a6453f54-541c96f3: undefined npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git npm WARN addRemoteGit     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roam ing\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:14:12) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo dules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:69:19) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo dules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:81:29) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul es\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:90:16 npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul es\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:44:5 npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul es\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:29:5 npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul es\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29 npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15) npm WARN addRemoteGit  webpack/compression-webpack-plugin#7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25 a660acc6a2a6453f54 resetting remote C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cac he\_git-remotes\git-github-com-webpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd5 4a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54-e286d0b5 because of error: { [Error: not found: g it] code: 'ENOGIT' } npm ERR! git clone
--template=C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_gi t-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:webpack/compression-webpack-plugin. git C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-w ebpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54-e 286d0b5: undefined npm ERR! git clone
--template=C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_gi t-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:webpack/compression-webpack-plugin. git C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-w ebpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54-e 286d0b5: undefined npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600 npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\irfanyounis\\App Data\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "angular- cli@latest" npm ERR! node v4.6.0 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9 npm ERR! code ENOGIT

npm ERR! not found: git npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed using git. npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself. npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request: npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log

C:\Windows\system32>
```

my PATH in enviroemt variables is as follows

"C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\irfanyounis\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_284a859b0e6deba86edc624fef1e4db2aa8241a9\cmd "

I'm using windows 7 64 bit.!

Answer (score 0):

As it says in error, you either dont have git installed or it is there but not available in PATH (I can't see it available in your path).

Please install GIT as admin, that will add it to PATH as well and then try reinstalling angular-cli